# Serialize Objects using xmlSerializer.Serialize and IEnumerable objects

Tags: serialization, interface

I have an object that holds an object that is definded as IEnumerable, i.e.

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("MyObject")]
public class MyObject
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlArrayAttribute("Numbers")]
    public IEnumerable<string> Numbers { get; set; }
}
```

When I run the XmlSerializer.Serialize against the object, i.e.

```
        MyObject myObject = new MyObject() { 
            Name = "My Name" ,
            Numbers= new List<string>(){"One", "Two"}
        };



     var xmlSerializer = XmlSerializer.FromTypes(new[] 
{ typeof(MyObject) })[0];
            using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(@"MyObject.xml"))
            {
                if (xmlWriter != null) xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, myObject);
            }
```

I get

> "Cannot serialize member
>   SerializeObjects.MyObject.Numbers of
>   type
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[System.String,
>   mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]
>   because it is an interface."

Which I understand that you can't serialize an interface.

Now for the question:

What is the best declaration for the "public IEnumerable Numbers { get; set; }"?

Should I use `List<>`, if not why not?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general terms, you should use `Collection<T>` if you intend users of your class to be free to modify it, or `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` if you do not. It is not recommended to use `List<T>` in public interfaces ([source](http://blogs.msdn.com/codeanalysis/archive/2006/04/27/faq-why-does-donotexposegenericlists-recommend-that-i-expose-collection-lt-t-gt-instead-of-list-lt-t-gt-david-kean.aspx)).

However, as this class is for XML Serialization and thus presumably isn't used for any purpose other than representing XML as an object model, the rules don't really apply in the same way as a 'normal' API because it will have no consumers other than the `XmlSerializer`, and so it doesn't really matter that much what you use. I'd probably still stick to the recommendations though.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind the list being editable i.e. Adding/Removing publically then `List<>` would be fine. Otherwise, you should use `ReadOnlyCollection`