# using interface and not concrete type IEnumerable cause an exception

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

It is better to work with interfaces and not with concrate type so our application will have modularity and freedom to use any desired type (as long it implements the interface);

So in my Worker object I created a member called CarNumbers in type IEnumerable:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "", Name = "Worker")]
public class Worker {
    ....
    ....
    [DataMember(IsRequired = false, Name = "CarNumbers")]
    public IEnumerable<string> CarNumbers  { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

Now I am trying to serialize Worker object into XML and I get the exception:

> Cannot serialize member Worker.CarNumbers of type System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[string]] because it is an interface.

How can I solve this exception without breaking the indepenedecy and using concrate type?

Comment: What are the possible type candidates for instantiating CarNumbers? If there is only one candidate, say, List<string> then it might be better to use it directly

Comment: @Sergey Kudriavtsev: It can be List, array and so on.

Comment: See the answers to this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729875/serialize-objects-using-xmlserializer-serialize-and-ienumerable-objects. There are other related questions that an answer. But in general you'll either have to change that type or provide some custom serialization code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the serializer.  In general, serialization needs to be able to create concrete types (otherwise, when deserializing how would it know what to actually create?  You can't create an instance of just an interface...) so you have to leak some of the abstraction somewhere.

That all said, using the [NetDataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.netdatacontractserializer.aspx) lets you do what you want from a code perspective, though all it does is persist the concrete types necessary in the serialized output.

Comment: What do you mean?  We use it regularly in our code instead of the regular DataContractSerializer when we need this kind of abstraction.

Comment: You right! I used DataContractSerializer and it didn't work. NetDataContractSerializer works great.What is the difference between DataContractSerializer and NetDataContractSerializer?

Comment: Look at the serialized output, for starters.