# XmlSerializer won't serialize IEnumerable

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I have an invocation logger that is intended to record all method calls along with the parameters associated with the method using XmlSerializer. It works well for most of the calls, but it throws an exception for all methods that has a parameter of `IEnumerable` type.

For example, `void MethodWithPlace( Place value )` would be serialized, but `void MethodWithPlace( IEnumerable<Place> value )` would not.

The exception is

> System.NotSupportedException: Cannot serialize interface
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[Place,
>   Test, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral]].

What should I do to make it work with those methods with `IEnumerable` as one of its parameters?

Comment: Can you replace the method definitions with a concrete implementation of IEnumerable, such as List<T>?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot serialize parameter of type 'System.Linq.Enumerable... ' when using WCF, LINQ, JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068897/cannot-serialize-parameter-of-type-system-linq-enumerable-when-using-wcf)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Serialize Objects using xmlSerializer.Serialize and IEnumerable objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729875/serialize-objects-using-xmlserializer-serialize-and-ienumerable-objects)

Comment: @evanM I wish I could, but I'm afraid that I'm not allowed to touch other part of the project.

Comment: How do you log a method, can you show the code?

Comment: Changed the title because `XmlSerializer` is not specific to C#

Answer (score 35):

The way you serialize an IEnumerable property is with a surrogate property

```
[XmlRoot]
public class Entity {
   [XmlIgnore]
   public IEnumerable<Foo> Foo { get; set; }

   [XmlElement, Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
   public List<Foo> FooSurrogate { get { return Foo.ToList(); } set { Foo = value; } }
}
```

It's ugly, but it gets the job done. The nicer solution is to write a surrogate class (i.e. EntitySurrogate).

Comment: Throwing `[Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]` on the surrogate will help hide it.  Also, may want to consider the ShouldSerialize* pattern. [Similar to this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10840603/425809).

Answer (score 13):

Basically an XmlSerializer can't serialize an interface.  The solution, then, is to give it a concrete instance to serialize.  Depending on how your invocation logger works, I would consider using

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(value.GetType());
```

Comment: What we did was to get all possible method parameters in a class and put them as extraTypes in the constructor of XmlSerializer. Then, we create a transparent proxy for that class, capture method calls, serialize them, and invoke the real method..

Answer (score 13):

I don't think you'll be able to serialize that.  Try converting the IEnumerable to a List and then you will be able to serialize.

Comment: Since I'm unable to change the method signature, is there any workaround that can possibly solve this problem?

Comment: You can if you were to just add the .ToList() to that Method Signature or should I say have it return the IEnumberable.ToList()

Comment: Can you use a different serializer, like the NetDataContractSerializer?  You will not be able to do it with the XML serializer.

Comment: You'll have to use a different serializer.  Say, for example, someone passes a non-serializable argument that inherits from IEnumerable<T>.  The XML serializer won't be able to handle it.

Comment: I think you are saying that you CANNOT modify the methods that are being logged, so you can't control if an IEnumerable is a parameter in the method that is being logged, correct?  So, then, can you modify the code that attempts to serialize this data and change any IEnumerable objects by using the .ToList() method on them before the serialization attempt is made?  Or, can you pass the logging to a middleman class that can turn any IEnumerables into Lists before passing it along to the Serializer?  Otherwise, I think you will need to have the method signatures modified as DJ KRAZE suggested.

Answer (score 3):

To be XML serializable, types which inherit from IEnumerable must have an implementation of Add(System.Object) at all levels of their inheritance hierarchy. {your class} does not implement Add(System.Object).

implement the Add() function, you might solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

XmlSerializer does not support this. Try [YAXLib](http://yaxlib.codeplex.com/) for these kinds serializations.

Comment: The url is broken. The right url is https://www.nuget.org/packages/YAXLib/ or https://www.nuget.org/packages/XSerializer/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best way, but it worked for me.
I created a method that makes serialization.

Use

var xml =  Util.ObjetoToXML(obj, null, null).OuterXml;

method

```
        public static XmlDocument ObjetoToXML(object obj, XmlDocument xmlDocument, XmlNode rootNode)
    {

        if (xmlDocument == null)
            xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();

        if (obj == null) return xmlDocument;

        Type type = obj.GetType();

        if (rootNode == null) { 
            rootNode = xmlDocument.CreateElement(string.Empty, type.Name, string.Empty);
            xmlDocument.AppendChild(rootNode);
        }

        if (type.IsPrimitive || type == typeof(Decimal) || type == typeof(String) || type == typeof(DateTime))
        {

            // Simples types
            if (obj != null)
                rootNode.InnerText = obj.ToString();

        }
        else if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>))
        {
            // Genericis types

            XmlNode node = null;

            foreach (var item in (IEnumerable)obj)
            {
                if (node == null)
                {
                    node = xmlDocument.CreateElement(string.Empty, item.GetType().Name, string.Empty);
                    node = rootNode.AppendChild(node);
                }


                ObjetoToXML(item, xmlDocument, node);
            }

        }
        else
        {

            // Classes types
            foreach (var propertie in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
            {

                XmlNode node = xmlDocument.CreateElement(string.Empty, propertie.Name, string.Empty);
                node = rootNode.AppendChild(node);
                var valor = propertie.GetValue(obj, null);

                ObjetoToXML(valor, xmlDocument, node);
            }

        }


        return xmlDocument;

    }
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use DataContractSerializer

```
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var serialiser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof (EnvironmentMetadata));
            serialiser.WriteObject(ms, environmentMetadata);

            var s = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ms.ToArray());
            return s;
        }
```

Comment: The question was about the XML Serializer, not the data contract serializer.