# How to serialize/deserialize optional XML enumeration in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I am trying to figure out how to serialize/deserialize an XML listing to C# that has an optional attribute that is an enumerated type. The following is my C# class:

```
public class AttributeAssignmentExpressionElement : XACMLElement
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string AttributeId { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public Category Category { get; set; }                   
}
```

My `Category` enumeration is defined as follows:

```
public enum Category
{
    [XmlEnum(Name = "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject")]
    Subject,
    [XmlEnum(Name = "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource")]
    Resource,
    [XmlEnum(Name = "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action")]
    Action,
    [XmlEnum(Name = "urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:environment")]        
    Environment
}
```

When `Category` is present in the corresponding XML file, serialization/deserialization works as expected. However if the `Category` is missing from the XML, the default value is used (first item in the enumeration). If I try to make the enumerated variable nullable (`Category?`), the deserializer throws an exception because it is unable to deserialize a complex type. Given the following XML (which does not contain the attribute), how can I serialize the enumeration appropriately?

```
<AttributeAssignmentExpression
    AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:example:attribute:text">       
</AttributeAssignmentExpression>
```

In this situation, the value in the deserialized object should be null.

Thanks for any help you can offer!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, you can do this - but it is a bit messy:

```
[XmlIgnore]
public Category? Category { get; set; }

[XmlAttribute("Category")]
[Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
public Category CategorySerialized
{
    get { return Category.Value; }
    set { Category = value; }
}
[Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
public bool ShouldSerializeCategorySerialized()
{
    return Category.HasValue;
}
```

What this does:

- uses a `Category?` for the optional enum value
- disables the `Category` property for serialization
- adds a secondary property, `CategorySerialized`, as a proxy to `Category`, which is non-nullable and hidden (as far as is possible) from the IDE etc
- use conditional serialization on `CategorySerialized` via the `ShouldSerialize*` pattern

Comment: That's close to what xsd writes if you start with a schema (which I recommend), except you don't need to have a separate property for the actual value. Just use the nullable type.

Comment: Actually - I implemented something very comparable to this using the XmlIgnore attribute..I was hoping for a cleaner way. Looks like this is the only way. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Actually, there's some official magic which allows to do this ([see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#code-snippet-5)):

> Another option is to use a special pattern to create a Boolean field recognized by the XmlSerializer, and to apply the XmlIgnoreAttribute to the field. The pattern is created in the form of propertyNameSpecified. For example, if there is a field named "MyFirstName" you would also create a field named "MyFirstNameSpecified" that instructs the XmlSerializer whether to generate the XML element named "MyFirstName". This is shown in the following example.

That is, the model in TS case should look like this:

```
public class AttributeAssignmentExpressionElement : XACMLElement
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string AttributeId { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public Category Category { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public bool CategorySpecified { get; set; }                   
}
```

Unless you set magic field `CategorySpecified` to `true`, `Category` attribute won't be serialized. In case of deserialization, `CategorySpecified` will be `false`, indicating that `Category` wasn't present in XML.

Answer (score 3):

The complete sample code using 'Specified' pattern

```
public class ClassToSerialize
{
    [XmlAttribute("attributeName")]
    public EnumType EnumPropertyValue
    {
        get { return EnumProperty.Value; }
        set { EnumProperty = value; }
    }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public EnumType? EnumProperty { get; set; }
    public bool EnumPropertyValueSpecified => EnumProperty.HasValue;

}
```