# How to use XmlInclude to serialize IEnumerable

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, xml-serialization, ienumerable

I've run into an issue with serializing an `IEnumerable` with the `XmlSerializer`. Since `IEnumerable` represents a list of `object`, `XmlSerializer` doesn't know ahead of time what types it needs to serialize. But because it needs to know, it throws an `InvalidOperationException` when it encounters a type other than `object`.

> The type Foo.Bar was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically.

The `XmlIncludeAttribute` is intended to be applied to a method to indicate that the return value can be a certain type. However, `IEnumerable` has no method that I could put the attribute on.

I tried applying them to `GetEnumerator`:

```
public class Bar : IEnumerable
{
    private List<object> list;

    public Bar()
    {
    }

    [XmlInclude(typeof(Bar))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(ChildBar))]
    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return list.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public void Add(Bar bar)
    {
        list.Add(bar);
    }

    public void Add(ChildBar childBar)
    {
        list.Add(childBar);
    }

    // used for deserialization
    public void Add(object o)
    {
        if (o is Bar || o is ChildBar)
        {
            list.Add(o);
        }
    }

    // more irrelevant stuff
}

public class ChildBar
{
    public ChildBar()
    {
    }

    // more irrelevant stuff
}
```

That didn't solve it, and I have no idea where else to use the attributes.

Where should I put them? Can I work around it without them? Can I avoid writing my own enumerator?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Since their were a couple flaws with my previous answer -didn't have bar containing more bars and didn't use xmlAttributes here is my new solution: This does not implement however...

EDIT: Well I've gone back and reviewed some things and this is my final solution by implementing ICollection, hope this helps anyone trying to find a solution to serializing Collections.

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var program = new Program();

        program.SerializeObject();
    }

    private int tierIndex = 1;

    public void SerializeObject()
    {
        var barCollection = new BarCollection();
            var bar1 = new Bar() { Name = "bar1" };
            barCollection.Add(bar1);
            var bar2 = new Bar() { Name = "bar2" };
            barCollection.Add(bar2);
                var bar3 = new Bar() { Name = "bar3" };
                bar2.BarCollection.Add(bar3);
                var bar4 = new Bar() { Name = "bar4" };
                bar2.BarCollection.Add(bar4);
            var bar5 = new Bar() { Name = "bar 5" };
            barCollection.Add(bar5);
            var bar6 = new Bar() { Name = "bar 6" };
            barCollection.Add(bar6);
                var bar7 = new Bar() { Name = "bar 7" };
                bar6.BarCollection.Add(bar7);
                    var bar8 = new Bar() { Name = "bar 8" };
                    bar7.BarCollection.Add(bar8);



        var x = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BarCollection));
        x.Serialize(Console.Out, barCollection);

        Console.WriteLine("\n");

        WriteCollection(barCollection);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public void WriteCollection(BarCollection barCollection)
    {
        tierIndex++;

        foreach (Bar bar in barCollection)
        {
            Console.Write(new StringBuilder().Insert(0, "--", tierIndex) + "> ");
            Console.Write(bar.Name + "\n");

            WriteCollection(bar.BarCollection);
        }

        tierIndex--;
    }
}

public class BarCollection : ICollection
{
    private readonly ArrayList barNodes = new ArrayList();

    public Bar this[int index]
    {
        get { return (Bar) barNodes[index]; }
    }

    public void CopyTo(Array a, int index)
    {
        barNodes.CopyTo(a, index);
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return barNodes.Count; }
    }

    public object SyncRoot
    {
        get { return this; }
    }

    public bool IsSynchronized
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return barNodes.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public void Add(Bar bar)
    {
        barNodes.Add(bar);
    }

    public void Add(Object bar)
    {
        barNodes.Add((Bar) bar);
    }
}

public class Bar
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Name")]
    public string Name;

    [XmlArray(ElementName = "BarNodes", IsNullable = true)]
    public BarCollection BarCollection = new BarCollection();
}
```

Heres the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="IBM437"?>
<ArrayOfBar xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <Bar Name="bar1">
    <BarNodes />
  </Bar>

  <Bar Name="bar2">
    <BarNodes>
      <Bar Name="bar3">
        <BarNodes />
      </Bar>

      <Bar Name="bar4">
        <BarNodes />
      </Bar>

    </BarNodes>
  </Bar>

  <Bar Name="bar 5">
    <BarNodes />
  </Bar>

  <Bar Name="bar 6">
    <BarNodes>
      <Bar Name="bar 7">
        <BarNodes>
          <Bar Name="bar 8">
            <BarNodes />
          </Bar>

        </BarNodes>
      </Bar>

    </BarNodes>
  </Bar>

</ArrayOfBar>

----> bar1
----> bar2
------> bar3
------> bar4
----> bar 5
----> bar 6
------> bar 7
--------> bar 8
```

Another Stack Reference: [XmlSerializer won't serialize IEnumerable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9102234/xmlserializer-in-c-sharp-wont-serialize-ienumerable)

Comment: Doesn't `IXmlSerializable` require that you write all the serialization code yourself? That could be a real pain for me. Is there no easier solution?

Comment: Yes the type (T) needs to implement `IXmlSerializable`. With the Read and Write methods they're not that hard to implement just say `writer.WriteStartElement("")` and `writer.WriteAttribute("")` etc. take a look at this too : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43237/How-to-Implement-IXmlSerializable-Correctly

Comment: Yea shouldn't say really easy because every class might have quite a bit of information that you want to write to an XML file. You could also loop through the fields of a class if you want to write all the fields to the XML file.

Comment: Do you have proof that `XmlSerializer` works inside a `WriteXml` method? The MSDN documentation makes me think it doesn't, since it mentions serializing documents, not elements.

Comment: What do you mean by documents and elements? - The XmlWriter writer that your passing in to the WriteXml method is the one Writing elements.

Comment: Yes, but you pass that writer to an `XmlSerializer`, and I'm not sure that it supports a partly-written document.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15975/discussion-between-dnxviral-and-kendall-frey)