# asp.net web api having trouble sending objects

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I've just switched to using the new web api for MVC 4, and I am having great difficulty in deserializing the response from my webservice.

This is my server code:

```
IEnumerable<Fish> myList = GetFish();

return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, myList,"application/xml");
```

This is serialised as:

`<ArrayOfFish xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MySolution.NameSpace.Resources\" />`

As there are no results returned.

When I try to parse this using the `XmlMediaTypeFormatter`, I get an error saying it wasn't expecting what it got.

My code to deserialise it hasn't changed from before I started using web api, and is simply:

`return content.ReadAsAsync<T>(formatters).Result;`

formatters is a `List` of formatters, containing only the `XmlMediaTypeFormatter`

T is a generic list of `Fish`

If I omit the `"application/xml"` type then it appears to send in JSon (as the result is []) however the client expects xml, and will not use a JSon serialiser on it for some reason, even if I explicitly put the type as `text/json`.

It should be fairly simple to deserialise objects as it's exactly what I was doing before, I've just changed my server very slightly to use `CreateResponse` to make a `HttpResponseMessage` instead of using `HttpResponseMessage<T>` directly, because the generic version isn't supported anymore. I can't find a single client/server example online of someone decoding the result into objects which is frustrating.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

An XmlSerializer can't serialize an interface (IEnumerable).  Convert to a List before returning.

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, myList.ToList(),"application/xml");
```

simlar question with references here - [XmlSerializer won't serialize IEnumerable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9102234/xmlserializer-in-c-sharp-wont-serialize-ienumerable)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up discovering that the serialization method web api uses is very slightly different to the former, standard way. I added this to my `global.asax` and it resolved the issue:

`GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Insert(0, new XmlMediaTypeFormatter() { UseXmlSerializer = true });`