# XmlSerializer error on early-bound Entity "ActivityPointers"

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, xmlserializer, early-binding

I'm getting a XmlSerializer error when I serialize an object with a refrence to an early-bound CRM entity. Have you seen anything like this and/or have any thoughts on how I can correct?...

*{"Cannot serialize member 'DataSync.ParseI17Xml.CrmEarlyBound.sevp_petition.sevp_petition_ActivityPointers' of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[DataSync.ParseI17Xml.CrmEarlyBound.ActivityPointer, DataSync.ParseI17Xml, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]', see inner exception for more details."}*

Is the problem that it can't serialize IEnumerables? I'm not sure.

Thanks for your advice! :-)

Comment: Any more detail in the inner exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I worked this out. It ended up being easier than I thought. The solution was to use a different serializer. The DataContractSerializer works perfectly.

[Serialize CRM entity using DataContractSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh675409.aspx)

I hope this helps someone :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try converting it to a List first using .ToList().

There was another answer for the same [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9102234/xmlserializer-wont-serialize-ienumerable)