# XmlSerializer not deserializing XML to IEnumerable

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

While referencing one of the Stack Overflow posts, [XmlSerializer won't serialize IEnumerable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9102234/xmlserializer-wont-serialize-ienumerable), I have the following code that would serialize to XML correctly but when deserialized back, the IEnumerable comes back empty.

```
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Hello{
    public static void Main(){

        // <!--- Serializing part -->
        Glossary glossary1 = new Glossary();
        glossary1.Term = "Test1";
        glossary1.Definition = "Test1";
        Glossary glossary2 = new Glossary();
        glossary2.Term = "Test2";
        glossary2.Definition = "Test2";
        List<Glossary> glossaryList = new List<Glossary>();
        glossaryList.Add(glossary1);
        glossaryList.Add(glossary2);
        GlossaryCollection glossary = new GlossaryCollection(glossaryList);

        XDocument doc = new XDocument();
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(GlossaryCollection));
        using (var writer = doc.CreateWriter()) {
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(writer, glossary);
        }

        doc.Save("test.xml");
        XDocument doc2 = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
        Console.WriteLine(glossary.glossaryList.Count());
        Console.WriteLine(doc2.ToString());
        //So far looks good - serializing works fine!
        // </!--- Serializing part -->      
        // <!--- De-Serializing part -->                

        GlossaryCollection temp2;
        xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(GlossaryCollection));
        using (var reader = doc2.Root.CreateReader()) {
            var temp = xmlSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
            temp2 = (GlossaryCollection) temp;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(temp2.glossaryList.Count()); // Results in 0, should be 2... :(
        // </!--- De-Serializing part -->               
    }
    [XmlRoot]
            public class GlossaryCollection {
                [XmlIgnore]
                    public IEnumerable<Glossary> glossaryList;
                [XmlElement]    
                    public List<Glossary> GlossarySurrogate { get { return glossaryList.ToList(); } set { glossaryList = value; } }  // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9102234/xmlserializer-wont-serialize-ienumerable   
                public GlossaryCollection() {
                    glossaryList = new List<Glossary>();
                }
                public GlossaryCollection(IEnumerable<Glossary> glossaryList) {
                    this.glossaryList = glossaryList;
                }
            }
        [XmlType("Glossary")]
                public class Glossary
                {
                        public string Id { get; set; }
                        public string Term { get; set; }
                        public string Definition { get; set; }
                }   
}
```

Update: Based on Iridium's answer, it does not seem possible to use IEnumerable with XmlSerializer since it was returning a new list everytime, so went with the approach of converting to a List. However if there is a solution (even if hacky) with keeping glossaryList an IEnumerable, do let me know - even if simply for pure curiosity.

Comment: Xmlnclude means that another class can inherit the base class.  So if you have [XmlInclude(typeof(Glossary))]  then you should have Glossary : GlossaryCollection.  And if you have [XmlInclude(typeof(GlossaryCollection))] then you should have GlossaryCollection : Glossary.   Now how can you have a child inherit a parent and the same parent inherit the child?

Comment: @jdweng Good catch, thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your XML-serialized type has a property of type `List<T>`, `XmlSerializer` will `get` the value of the property, then call `.Add(...)` to add the deserialized elements (i.e. it does *not* `set` the property).

Since the getter for the `GlossarySurrogate` property returns a new list every time you `get` it, the changes the XML serializer makes to the result are lost.

If you want this to work correctly, you're going to need to convert your `glossaryList` field to a `List<Glossary>` and return it directly from the `GlossarySurrogate` getter, without calling `.ToList()` on it.