# Web Service Giving Error Can not serialize interface

Tags: vb.net, asmx, webservice-client

Working on VB.net, Webservice I created in the UI Project Now I am running the Application And Accessing the Web service with parameters like HTTP://localhost:3000/TestWebService.asmx/2011 and it is giving an error
Can not serialize Interface System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, Although Error is also not handled by the Global Exception method.

```
<WebMethod(EnableSession:=True)>
Public Function GetTest (ByVal P As Integer) As IEnumerable (of Test)

End Function
```

Comment: I tried with a different name also giving the same error

Comment: Does [XmlSerializer won't serialize IEnumerable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9102234/xmlserializer-wont-serialize-ienumerable) help?